# Corrupted TAR File Error Upon Access From Google Cloud Storage in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, tar, archive

I am storing a TAR file in Google Cloud Storage. The file can be successfully downloaded via `gsutil` and extracted in my computer using macOS Archive Utility. However, the Java program that I implement always encounter `java.io.IOException: Corrupted TAR archive` upon accessing the file. I have tried several ways and all of them are utilizing the `org.apache.commons:commons-compress` library. Can you give me insight on how to fix this problem or something that I can try on?


Here are the implementations that I have tried:

```java
Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_PATH);
blob.downloadTo(Paths.get("filename.tar"));
String contentType = blob.getContentType(); // application/x-tar

InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(blob.reader());
String mime = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is); // null
TarArchiveInputStream ais = new TarArchiveInputStream(is);
ais.getNextEntry(); // raise java.io.IOException: Corrupted TAR archive

InputStream is2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(blob.getContent());
String mime2 = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is2); // null
TarArchiveInputStream ais2 = new TarArchiveInputStream(is2);
ais2.getNextEntry(); // raise java.io.IOException: Corrupted TAR archive

InputStream is3 = new FileInputStream("filename.tar");
String mime3 = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is3); // null
TarArchiveInputStream ais3 = new TarArchiveInputStream(is3);
ais3.getNextEntry(); // raise java.io.IOException: Corrupted TAR archive

TarFile file = new TarFile(blob.getContent()); // raise java.io.IOException: Corrupted TAR archive
TarFile tarFile = new TarFile(Paths.get("filename.tar")); // raise java.io.IOException: Corrupted TAR archive
```

Addition: I have tried to parse a JSON from GCS and it's working fine.

```
Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_PATH);
JSONTokener jt = new JSONTokener(Channels.newInputStream(blob.reader()));
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jt);
```

Comment: It's possible that the tar file uses features that the Java tar implementation doesn't support. I don't know how these kinds of features (think extended permissions, acls, ...) are implemented in tar, some formats do it in a backwards-compatible way, I don't know if tar does. I suspect this is not actually related to GCS. Have you tried using the original tar without uploading/downloading it?

Comment: I have tried accessing that tar file directly via `FileInputStream` from my local directory, the same error still persists. I tried to create a random file that was archived into tar by running the command `$ tar -cvf <filename>.tar <random-dir>`, the tar file is accessible using the same `FileInputStream`. I think based on these facts we can eliminate some possibilities, it should not be caused by the Spring GCS nor the `commons-compress` library. [Here](https://github.com/idrpambudi/file-archive/raw/main/latest.tar) is the "corrupted" tar file if it might be helpful for inspection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `tar` is compressed, it is a `tgz` file.

For that reason, you need to decompress the file when processing your tar contents.

Please, consider the following example; note the use of the common compress builtin `GzipCompressorInputStream` class:

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
  final File archiveFile = new File("latest.tar");
  try (
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(archiveFile);
      GzipCompressorInputStream gzIn = new GzipCompressorInputStream(in);
      TarArchiveInputStream tarIn = new TarArchiveInputStream(gzIn)
  ) {
    TarArchiveEntry tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
    while (tarEntry != null) {
      final File path = new File("/tmp/" + File.separator + tarEntry.getName());
      if (!path.getParentFile().exists()) {
        path.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }

      if (!tarEntry.isDirectory()) {
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path)){
          IOUtils.copy(tarIn, out);
        }
      }
      tarEntry = tarIn.getNextTarEntry();
    }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```